# xor над строками

Tags: c#, алгоритм, криптография

Я реализую шифр Вернама. Вот метод, который отвечает за процесс шифрования:

```
static string[] VernamCipher(char[] _message, char[] _key)
    {

        string[] message = GetBinaryArray(_message);
        string[] key = GetBinaryArray(_key);


       // return ...
    }
```

В качестве параметра передается строка, буквы которого записаны в массив char, и сам ключ, который тоже в виде массива char. Длинна ключа и сообщения совпадают.

Потом я создал метод GetBinaryArray:

```
static string[] GetBinaryArray(char[] array)
    {
        var ASCIIBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(array);
        var BinaryArray = new string[array.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            BinaryArray[i] = (Convert.ToString(ASCIIBytes[i], 2)).PadLeft(8, '0');
        }

        return BinaryArray;
    }
```

Он берёт номер значения символа в массиве по таблице ASCII и преобразует его в двоичный код. Этот код записывается в строковый массив и возвращается методом.

Теперь, я хочу выполнить операцию XOR с элементами массивов message и key.Потом перевести каждый элемент массива в десятичный код ACSII и преобразовать его в соответствующий знак.
И в конце вернуть методом этих знаков массив. То бишь, сделать эдакую инверсию того, что мы делали в методе GetBinaryArray.

Я не имею даже представления, как это можно сделать, да и вообще, можно ли операцию XOR применять со строками.

Comment: Зачем в двоичный вид переводить-то, не нужно оно...

Answer (score 1):

Двоичные операции реализованы над байтами, не над строками. Поэтому я бы перевёл строку в массив байт ([`Encoding.GetBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getbytes(v=vs.110).aspx)), про-xor-ил с ключом (который тоже должен быть набором байт, а не символов), и полученный массив байт был бы результатом.

Теперь, что у вас категорически неправильно. GetBinaryArray должен возвращать массив байт, а не каких-то строк. `Convert.ToString` не нужно.

Затем, Encoding.ASCII — катастрофически неправильно. Ваша строка имеет право содержать символы не только английского алфавита.

Итого:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message).Zip(key, (a, b) => (byte)(a ^ b)).ToArray()
```

при условии, что размера ключа хватает.